# Accuracy of monte carlo simulation to calcualate π

Tags: math, pi

I have created a [website](http://monte-carlo.serialpowered.com) which uses a Monte Carlo simulation to calculate π, there are currently `3202959700000` 'dots' and `2515023487209` are in the circle. Plugging this into the formula `4 * 2515023487209 / 3202959700000` returns `3.1408743446993728956377440527897` which is quite incorrect. Is this wrong since there just aren't enough 'dots' or did I just misplace them?

Comment: i think you will find that the quality of your random number generator has a direct effect on your results.

Comment: Could you report how you generate the random points and how you determine if it is inside the circle? It might be that the figure you test is not a full circle.

Comment: @LutzL this is the code I use to create the dots, measure their distance and then determine if they're in the circle https://jsfiddle.net/q3c1jptb/

Comment: @EvilTeach I see, I create the random numbers using JS so by increasing the quality of the random function I also reduce the amount of dots :(

Comment: When I did it on a trash 80 back in the 70s, i got 3.1 out of it.  I believe the period of the PRG was about 256, and he resolution of the points was low.  I think there were 6 rectangles in one character cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
var size = 500;
var Xpos = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
var Ypos = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
var dist = Math.hypot(Xpos - size / 2, Ypos - size / 2);
```

produces random coordinates in the range 0..499. This is not a uniform sampling of the interval 0..500, and thus one has to expect errors in the computation. One first fix is to add 0.5 to the coordinates so that the big square is subdivided into smaller squares that are represented by their centers. But in the end the accuracy of that method can not be better than counting the squares in the 500x500 subdivision that lie "mostly" inside the circle.

Comment: I understand the problem, although to the solution I would think of is creating numbers from 0...500 instead of 0...499, but if I understand you correctly you mean I would have to rewrite it like this right?
`var Xpos = Math.floor(Math.random() * size) + 0.5;` for both the axises

Comment: Yes. This is like changing in numerical integration from left Riemann sums to midpoint sums. But you are still approximating the area of a pixelated circle, not the round circle.

Comment: Would the best solution be to increase the 'resolution' of the field in order to make it a less pixilated circle?

Comment: Yes. But why do you round at all? You need it to put a pixel on the screen, but for the computation no rounding at all would be best.

Answer (score 3):

Using a Monte Carlo simulation to calculate pi is *very* slow. For example, [this demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iu4LsqUtfh0) used 1 million points and got 3.16. You're going to need an absurd number of dots to refine that estimate much further.

Calculating pi is a nice way to learn about Monte Carlo simulations, but if you're really concerned with getting as many digits as possible, quickly, I'd point you to the [Chudnovsky Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm).

Comment: Ah, Thanks! I dont really need to get as many digits as possible I was just worried that something had gone wrong.

Comment: I think the linked demonstration is a good example of how you can produce bad random numbers. Particularly the line `rand() % (INTERVAL + 1)` does **_not_** produce uniformly distributed values given that `INTERVAL` is `1000`. So @Schotsl, if you want some real feedback - show us your real code.

Comment: @SergGr I've uploaded the code that generates the 'dots' here: https://jsfiddle.net/q3c1jptb and now that you have mentioned the problem with using +1 I already see one problem with my code.